# What does 'nine-and-twenty' mean?

Tags: meaning, numbers

Exactly as the title, what does "nine-and-twenty" mean?

Here's an example of sentence:

> Afraid of him! No, indeed! But I wish you will consider that **a man of
> nine-and-twenty** won’t relish having his affairs meddled with. Besides,
> he will very likely wonder what the deuce it has to do with me, and
> I’m sure I can’t tell him! I wish I had not come.
>
> [*The Corinthian*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nqX8KToXAJEC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=Afraid+of+him!+No,+indeed!+But+I+wish+you+will+consider+that+a+man+of+nine-and-twenty+won%E2%80%99t+relish+having+his+affairs+meddled+with.+Besides,+he+will+very+likely+wonder+what+the+deuce+it+has+to+do+with+me,+and+I%E2%80%99m+sure+I+can%E2%80%99t+tell+him!+I+wish+I+had+not+come.&source=bl&ots=Kp8wWPdd1i&sig=-wNZA8UGYgEzSdJ-6F5xT6QWqeU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLqZKt0pPPAhViDsAKHXW3A6QQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=Afraid%20of%20him!%20No%2C%20indeed!%20But%20I%20wish%20you%20will%20consider%20that%20a%20man%20of%20nine-and-twenty%20won%E2%80%99t%20relish%20having%20his%20affairs%20meddled%20with.%20Besides%2C%20he%20will%20very%20likely%20wonder%20what%20the%20deuce%20it%20has%20to%20do%20with%20me%2C%20and%20I%E2%80%99m%20sure%20I%20can%E2%80%99t%20tell%20him!%20I%20wish%20I%20had%20not%20come.&f=false), Georgette Heyer, 1940

Comment: Well, just what do you think it means? Come on, give it a try. What can it possibly mean?

Answer (score 0):

It's an archaic form of saying "Twenty Nine".  Most probably this is a paraphrasing of the nursery rhyme "Sing a song of sixpence":

> Four and twenty blackbirds, baked in a pie

Comment: Unlikely to be a paraphrasing of something unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

It is just an way to write twenty-nine that has fallen out of use.

Have a look at [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nine+and+twenty%2Ctwenty-nine&year_start=1400&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnine%20and%20twenty%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwenty%20-%20nine%3B%2Cc0), you can clearly see that in the first half of the eighteenth century the modern number word order took off.

Since it is a book another suspicion falls flat. A botched translation from one of the many languages that have exactly that kind of word order, like German, and Dutch for example.

Comment: It is not a botched translation; it is an author deliberately using archaic language a book set in the early 19th century.

Comment: @PeterShor It's what I said, that suspicion falls flat.